# decorView.systemUiVisibility deprecated. How to replace it correctly?

Tags: android

I have these lines in an old project (activity onCreate):

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

And another one:

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = window.decorView.systemUiVisibility or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
```

I'm not sure, that I understand, what is it. And most important, I don't know, how to rewrite it correctly, cause it's already deprecated. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this methode to change status bar  with new api or old  :

```
  private fun changeSystemStatusBarColor() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val window = window
            val decorView = window.decorView
            val wic = WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, decorView)
            wic.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = false // true or false as desired.
            // And then you can set any background color to the status bar.
            window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(
                this,
                R.color.black
            )
        } else {
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR; //  set status text dark
            window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(
                this,
                R.color.black
            )
        }
        setStatusBarLightText(window, true)
        return
    }

    private fun setStatusBarLightText(window: Window, isLight: Boolean) {
        setStatusBarLightTextOldApi(window, isLight)
        setStatusBarLightTextNewApi(window, isLight)
    }

    private fun setStatusBarLightTextOldApi(window: Window, isLight: Boolean) {
        val decorView = window.decorView
        decorView.systemUiVisibility =
            if (isLight) {
                decorView.systemUiVisibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv()
            } else {
                decorView.systemUiVisibility or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
            }
    }

    private fun setStatusBarLightTextNewApi(window: Window, isLightText: Boolean) {
        ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView)?.apply {
            // Light text == dark status bar
            isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !isLightText
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you tell me please which of these methods corresponds to the first case in my question, and which to the second?

Comment: as mention in the comments of the function changeSystemStatusBarColor if you use api > Build.VERSION_CODES.M Aka new api you should use the WindowInsetsControllerCompat like if block else block for old api